# Why React not understanding tag <br /> in string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need

```js
const stringWithBr = 'aaaaaaa<br />bbbbbbb';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>{stringWithBr}</div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

help, why this example not working?
in fact i need get:

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
```

Comment: React escapes the contents of the string you replace for security reason. If `stringWithBr` was a user provided string you do **not** want it to be evaluated as HTML. You want to use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of React against XSS.

It provides `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as an escape hatch and it's documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).

If possible, please avoid using this, though, especially if the input can be injected by the user somehow.